# adding custom font doesn't work iOS

Tags: ios, swift

Hello I need to add some Font in my playground, the first one works and the second doesen't work, I downloaded a font, installed it, added in resources folder and added in Xcode with this code, but it doesn't work, someone can help me?

```
let fontURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "VAGRoundedBold", withExtension: "ttf")
        CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL(fontURL! as CFURL, CTFontManagerScope.process, nil)    
let fontURL3 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "conduit_itc", withExtension: "ttf")
        CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL3(fontURL! as CFURL, CTFontManagerScope.process, nil) 

    buttonYellow.setTitle("Optimism", for: .normal)
    buttonYellow.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "VAGRoundedBold", size: 40)
    buttonRed.setTitle("Strenght", for: .normal)
    buttonRed.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"conduit_itc", size: 40)
```

EDIT. I don't know what was the problem, but downloading from dafont work, download from other website doesn't work

Comment: restart xcode will work

Comment: there are no errors but the font doesn't change

Comment: lol I don't know, I added another font with the same code and works

Answer (score 0):

- First: Add downloaded font to your project
- Second: Open `Info.plist` and add

  `<key>UIAppFonts</key>
  <array>
      <string> VAGRoundedBold.ttf</string>
  </array>`
- Last: Using your font with

`let yourFont = UIFont(name: "VAGRoundedBold", size: <your_size>)!`